# Firefox, add-on update when starting, how to change that?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, boot

I found very annoying that when opening Firefox (3.5) all extension popup for update. Is there a way to have not this popup right from the start. When I start a browser is often because I have task to do right now with it... It would be better if it would not act like a nag screen. Is there a way to customize this update screen?

### Edit:

I do not want to take it off completely but to not block the start of the browser loading.

Comment: Duplicate of this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105766/how-to-disable-firefox-add-ons-update-check-on-start

Comment: I do not want to disable it, I want to delay the update to not have the popup at start. They are no way to know that it has update but without blocking the start of the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update options are located in tools->options..->advanced->update on the windows version.